# How to go about using selenium to navigate page and click onto another page?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Basically, I want to navigate from this website https://www.neds.com.au/racing to this page https://www.neds.com.au/racing/belmont/2d6e712e-298b-4061-8e4d-fbef8c754b85.

There is not one xpath I can use though. The xpath's are:

`//*[@id="page-content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]/a/div[1]/span` (Belmont)

`//*[@id="page-content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]/ul/li[9]/a/span[1]` (R9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Note there is a space after 'Belmont '.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='Belmont ']").click()
```

A more robust way would be using `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[.='Belmont ']"))).click()
```

, which requires these imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain to me how you changed the xpath for 'Belmont' into that piece of code (("//span[.='Belmont ']").

Comment: That's still an `xpath` expresion, just not the *full* xpath, which is what you provided in the question. Full xpaths are the easy option but can be quite unreliable, so best to avoid. There are loads of simple tutorials on the subject. It's easier than it may look.